# UITableView not rotating even after using autoresize mask and shouldAutororateForInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, uitableview, rotation

I have a UIView, that contains a navigation bar, and UITableView. I implemented a UIViewController that implements a UITableViewDelegate. I over-rided the shouldAutorotateForInterfaceOrientation for the UIViewController to return YES for landscape and portrait mode. But the View does not seem to rotate. I did a similar thing without the Navigation bar and the Tableview and the view rotates.

Is is something i am missing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override -shouldAutorotateForInterfaceOrientation: in your UIViewController, not the view itself.